# Disable a button based on default values for two dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two dropdownlist and a disabled button. On load of the page, the button is disabled.
Once either of the dropdown is selected the button is enabled.

I want a situation where if the defaults of the two dropdownlist is 
`"select a branch"` and `"select a city"`, the submit button is disabled.

Is this possible? Is there a function in jQuery that can do this. More of a watcher.

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlrt", Model.Yoma, "Select a branch", new { @class = "kel" })
@Html.DropDownList("ddlre", Model.Kuma, "Select a City", new { @class = "kel" })
<button id="mySubmit" class="btnyoma" disabled>Submit</button>
<script>
    //Other Items can go here
   $("#ddlrt").change(function () {                 
       $('.sendbtn').removeAttr("disabled");
   });

   //other items can end here
   $("#ddlre").change(function () {
       $('.sendbtn').removeAttr("disabled");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: So add a change event to both and call a common function that checks the values of both.

Comment: Just check if the value exists - `$("#ddlrt").change(function () { if ($(this).val()) { $('.sendbtn').removeAttr("disabled"); } });`

Comment: Thanks. I already have change event for both. What were you thinking? Do you have any code sample?

Comment: 'What were you thinking?' ? thats nice when people are trying to help! You could be more helpful and provide a fiddle!

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I don't understand what you mean. Is that not a repetition of what I have?

Comment: Here is what am thinking. I want a situation where if the defaults/value selected of the two dropdownlist is "select a branch" and "select a city", the submit button should be  disabled.

Comment: @user2320476, No its not. Its only removing the `disabled` attribute if the `<select>` element has a value (and if the "Select a branch" option is selected it will not have a value)

Comment: just get the value of selectbox if its empty(equal to select a city and select a branch) then make the button disable

Comment: @user2320476, But the real question is why are you doing this instead of using client side validation and using a model with validation attributes?

Comment: Well, I didn't know I could use model validation attributes. How does that work?

Comment: @user2320476, Suggest you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials. What you doing is not the correct approach and you need to repeat all the validation again on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```
$("#ddlrt, #ddlre").change(function () {
    if ($('#ddlrt').val() || $('#ddlre').val())
        $('.sendbtn').prop("disabled", false);
    else
        $('.sendbtn').prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: What  are you trying to achieve with if ($('#ddlrt').val() || $('#ddlre').val()) ?

Comment: `if ($('#ddlrt').val() || $('#ddlre').val())` will check either both dropdown has value or not. @user2320476

Answer (score 0):

Please you can do for both dropdown like this way......

```
  $("#ddlrt").change(function () {
        var ddlValue = $("#ddlrt").val();
        if (ddlValue == "")
            $("#mySubmit").prop('disabled', true);
        else
            $("#mySubmit").prop('disabled', false);
    });
```